# [ROS 2] How is the name of the typesupport library generated?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a package where I create custom messages.

In my application I create a subscription that uses this custom type.
If I look into the RMW implementation code (FastRTPS for example) I think I found where the typesupport library is loaded

```
  const rosidl_message_type_support_t * type_support = get_message_typesupport_handle(
    type_supports, rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c__identifier);
  if (!type_support) {
    type_support = get_message_typesupport_handle(
      type_supports, rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp::typesupport_identifier);
    if (!type_support) {
      RMW_SET_ERROR_MSG("type support not from this implementation");
      return nullptr;
    }
  }
```

https://github.com/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/blob/09826ff401161fdf5fca63552d1a72a15907d53d/rmw_fastrtps_dynamic_cpp/src/rmw_subscription.cpp#L110

As you can see, this uses a `type_supports` handle and an identifier.
These are used to genereate the name of a shared library (for example `my_custom_msg_rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp`)

I would like to know where is the code that generates that name

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340301/%5Bros-2%5D-how-is-the-name-of-the-typesupport-library-generated?/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2019-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rosidl_typesupport_cpp` performs the dispatch (in case there is more than one typesupport library available for C++). It happens in this file: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_typesupport/blob/1769ba822b64573a450b8fe6a716d92deba9256e/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/src/type_support_dispatch.hpp#L63-L67

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0